# On the Jacobian determinant for conversion to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

I have an exercise that asks to compute the triple integral over a region $E$ (a paraboloid with a horizontal slice), which I know to be
$$\iiint_E x\,dV=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_{6y^2+6z^2}^6x\,dx\,dz\,dy=12\pi$$
I computed the result via a conversion to cylindrical coordinates at first by using the following parameters:
$$\begin{cases}x=x\\
y=r\sin t\\
z=r\cos t\end{cases}$$
To compute the determinant of the Jacobian, I have
$$|J|=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\sin t&\cos t\\0&r\cos t&-r\sin t\end{vmatrix}=-r$$
However, if I were to swap $x$ and $z$ (so that the paraboloid were oriented along the $z$ axis in place of the $x$ axis) and use the usual parameters,
$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\y=r\sin t\\z=z\end{cases}$$
I get the usual Jacobian, $|J|=r$. I felt I trusted this result more, so I stuck with this one to get $12\pi$.

Why is there a discrepancy here? Does the order of the partial derivatives in the Jacobian matter?

Comment: A very good question, I recently came along exact this problem!

Comment: @user170231 if you converted to cylindrical coordinates with the $x$-axis in place of the $z$-axis, wouldn't you have $x = x$, $y = r\color{red}{\cos(t)}$, $z = r\color{red}{\sin(t)}$ instead?

Comment: When you set up the integral, you have to multiply by the absolute value of the Jacobian; so the order of the partial derivatives doesn't matter.

Comment: @kobe Would that make a difference? I thought one could parameterize the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ (or $z$ in place of $x$) regardless of whether you let $x=r\cos t$ and $y=r\sin t$, or $x=r\sin t$ and $y=r\cos t$. Then again, I suppose this changes the direction of the circular path, with the former starting at $(1,0)$ and traversed counterclockwise, and the latter starting at $(1,0)$ and traversed clockwise (starting points in the x-y plane). This would then contribute a factor of $-1$ to the integral, then, right?

Comment: @user84413 is that so? I was under the impression that $J$ was the matrix of partial derivatives, and $|J|$ was the determinant of $J$. I do recall having to take the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant in a probability context (using the method of transformations), but I don't think I've ever had to take the absolute value in coordinate conversion...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's correct.  (The notation can be confusing, since the symbols for absolute value and determinant are the same, so some books use a different symbol for the determinant in this context.)

Comment: @user170231 yes, you're supposed to take the absolute value of the Jacobian. The $J$ usually stands for the determinant of the Jacobian matrix. See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx) for the statement and examples.

Comment: The link contains double integrals, but it extends to triple integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you must take the absolute value of the jacobian. Both the change of variables are correct.

Take a closer look to the different diffeomorphisms of the two changes of variables. They are 
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\Phi:&   \mathbb R^3& \to & \mathbb R^3\\ 
        & \begin{pmatrix} r\\t\\z\end{pmatrix}&\mapsto & \begin{pmatrix} r\cos(t)\\r\sin(t)\\z\end{pmatrix}\end{array} $$
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\Psi:&   \mathbb R^3& \to & \mathbb R^3\\ 
        & \begin{pmatrix} r\\t\\x\end{pmatrix}&\mapsto & \begin{pmatrix} x\\r\sin(t)\\r\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}\end{array} $$

As you can see, 
$$A\Phi((r,t,z)^T)=
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r\cos(t) \\r\sin(t) \\z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} z\\r\sin(t)\\r\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}
=
\Psi((r,t,z)^T)
$$

The matrix $A$ has determinant $-1$ and is a simmetry of $\mathbb R^3$ in itself. 
Since $A$ does not depend on the variables and because of Binet's theorem,
$$J_{\Psi}=AJ_{\Phi}\implies \text{det}(J_{\Psi})=-\text{det}(J_{\Phi})$$
Since we usually want volume to be positive we usually take $|\text{det}(J)|$ over $\text{det}(J)$ as you did: this follows intuitively if you believe that symmetrical shapes have the same volume.

Moreover, a simmetry *flips* the normal vectors of surfaces in certain directions. For instance ,the normal vector $(0,1)$ on top of a circle in $\mathbb R^2$ becomes $(0,-1)$ when you apply the simmetry $(x,y)\mapsto(x,-y)$.

A minus sign in your calculations of $\text {det}(J)$ shows that you have inverted the [orientation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability)  of your surface while changing coordinates, so you have "flipped" some normal vectors. Nothing to worry about when calculating volumes!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only detail I had overlooked when I first posted this question was that one takes the *absolute value* of the Jacobian determinant.